# How to make a shortened border?

Tags: html, css

How to make a shortened border on a div when you hover over as in the picture?

[image]

Comment: make a shorter box that is the length of the small/short border and the height of the small/short border. on hover of the large box runs a function where the right and bottom border of the small box turn red. make sure the z-index is above the large box so the small box's right and bottom border show.

Answer (score 1):

You can user the pseudo element `:after`, so it will be something like this:

```css
.square {
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.square:hover:after {
  content: "";
  height: 68px;
  width: 68px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  right: -3px;
  bottom: -3px;
  border-left: 0;
  border-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.border{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.border:hover:after {
  content: "";
  border-right: 5px solid red;
   border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 20px;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
</div>
```

Should get you out of trouble.

Also see the fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldg5h19a/)